# Syntax highlighting not working in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, syntax-highlighting

Visual Studio Professional 2022, ReSharper 2022.

When writing some "normal" C# code in Visual Studio I hit a problem where all syntax highlighting was lost, with some unusual compiler errors. Syntax highlighting continues to work as expected in all other files.

The compiler errors show differently in different locations:

- When hovering on the file: "An expression is too long or complex to compile"
- Within the file: "Argument is 'ref' while parameter is declared as 'value'"

[image: An expression is too long or complex to compile]

[image: Argument is ref while parameter is declared as value]

As seen in the second image, the code causing the error is the following:

```
public class Location : ILocation
{
    public int InventoryId { get; }
    public IReferences References { get; }

    public Location(IInventoryLocation location)
    {
        var shortRef = location.References
            .Single(ref => ref.ReferenceType == ReferenceType.Short);

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the problem but posted here in case it helps others. I was using `ref` as the name of the lambda variable, which is of course a keyword in C#. Changing this to `reference` or anything else restores the syntax highlighting. Of course the compiler error within the file makes it quite clear but it wasn't the error being presented to me initially. I tried a few other keywords, and only `ref` seems to break the syntax highlighting. StackOverflow's syntax highlighting is in fact better at revealing the issue!

Comment: StackOverflow's syntax highlighting is very dumb and does more or less only a keyword search. It knows nothing about the logical context.

Comment: You could mark it as the answer.